# PHP FTP connection in a Session

Tags: php, session, ftp

Im having trouble with a PHP FTP connection after it has been put into a session variable.

I have the index.php do a general check of input info and then directs to connect.php where it makes the connection and logs in. Once it has logged in it directs to setup.php. Setup is meant to download the relavent files but when I point to the session variable for FTP methods it only returns false/null. I have tried making a connection, changing dir, etc without sessions and that works. I have also tried putting the session variable into a variable but that doesn't work. I have made sure that the FTP variable is put into the session. What am I doing wrong?

```
//setup.php
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['conn_id']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}

$dir = "/home/oliver/";

ftp_chdir($_SESSION['conn_id'], $dir);
var_dump(ftp_nlist($_SESSION['conn_id'], "."));

ftp_close($_SESSION['conn_id']);
```

Thanks

Comment: `ftp_connect()` returns `resource`, I'm not sure you can keep it in session.

Comment: not possible. you can't serialize a resource like that. the ftp module is NOT going to reconnect to the ftp server for you if/when the session is loaded again later, and the ftp server itself won't try to keep things going in the faint hope that the client (php) will reconnect at some future point.

Comment: @DeDee thanks. what other way could/should I use to connect or should I just keep remaking a connection?

Comment: You have to reconnect each time.

Answer (score 1):

The `ftp_connect` returns a resource. It's like a pointer (index) to a table of connections. The table is valid only for lifetime of the PHP script. So if you transfer the pointer to another script instance, it points to an invalid entry.

If you need to share FTP connection between script instances, you probably need to implement some daemon (local server).

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a `ftp_connect` in a session variable. My suggestion would be to store the credentials for logging in, in a `$_SESSION` variable and then on the separate page just use the credentials you have stored to create a `ftp_connect` that you can use to do what you need to do. If you need to have the current directory then you are going to have to send that with every request.

Answer (score 0):

The `ftp_connect` function returns a data of type `resource`, as munitioned in the official docs here [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) :

> Warning
> Because session data is serialized, resource variables cannot be stored in the session.

so obviously you can't do that, one solution is to save the connection into a file instead of session storage.